# How to add header to request in Jquery Ajax?

Tags: ajax, header, request-headers, jquery-ajaxq

I'm trying to add header to request in Ajax with JQuery.

Below is the code :-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/core-service/services/v1.0/patients/registerPatients",
    data: JSON.stringify(patientDTO),
    //crossDomain : true,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN" : tokken},
    success: function(patientDTO) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", patientDTO);
        /* location.href = "fieldagentHRA.html";*/
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("patUrn", patientDTO.data);
            location.href="fieldagentHRA.html";
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    display(e);
    },
    done: function(e) {
    enableRegisterButton(true);
    }
});
```

I inspected this with chrome and found that header's body is not being added.[image: Without Header Body]

Then I used [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) (**Requestly is chrome+firefox plugin with which we can manually add a header to the request**).

After manually adding header :-

[image: After Manually Adding the header]

In both the pics request header x-auth-token is present in "ACCESS-CONTROL-REQUEST-HEADERS" but "X-AUTH-TOKEN" header along with header value is present in second pic which is not there in the first pic.

So my question is how to add request headers in Ajax with JQuery ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are couple of solutions depending on what you want to do

> If want to add a custom header (or set of headers) to an individual request then just add the `headers` property and this will help you to send your request with headers.

```
// Request with custom header
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});
```

> If want to add a default header (or set of headers) to every request then use `$.ajaxSetup():` this will help you to add headers.

```
//Setup headers here and than call ajax
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});

// Sends your ajax
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar' });
```

> add a header (or set of headers) to every request then use the beforeSend hook with $.ajaxSetup():

```
//Hook your headers here and set it with before send function.
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-my-custom-header', 'some value');
    }
});

// Sends your ajax
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar' });
```

> [Reference Link : AjaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)
>
> [Reference Link : AjaxHeaders](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)