# jQuery, How do I format a JSON request with authorization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, curl

I'm new to JSON requests, cURL, etc. and I can't figure out how to correctly format a JSON request with authorization. I'm trying to call on a Spotify API and they reccomend a cURL request:

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/search
```

and

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ReallyLongKey"
```

I don't know how to use cURL and GET so I tried to use ajax:

```
function Search() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5',
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(Data) {
            //stuff
        }
    });
}
```

How do I use cURL or add authentication to the ajax method? Thanks in advance,
Justin.

Comment: use `headers` field in `ajax` request? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929654/how-to-add-header-to-request-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: I tried that, got this error.
SpotifyTest.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track%2Cartist&market=US&limit=10&offset=5&_=1541708047402' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field X-AUTH-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. 
Although that's unrelated to the Auth-Token I think.

Comment: Did you check documentation? https://developer.spotify.com/

Comment: Yeah, they only go over this method:
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ReallyLongKey"
Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Did you create your application in spotify developer? Did you authenticate and acquire the key? Make sure that you are familiar with this: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/, it is not just simple `curl` request.